# Dynamic Multiple Dropdown list with append method not working

Tags: jquery

my problem is that in browser my dynamic multiple drop down select list not showing at all !!
i m using append method like that.

i have two drop down, when click on item in first drop down, in show data to secound dro pdown (is multiple), but in secound dropdown don show data, but data loaded in HTML (when insept dropdown with chrome).

first dropdown :
[first dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2BDS.png)

secound drop down (multiple) :
[secound drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8zZz.png)

and insept dropdown :
[insept dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPBL6.jpg)

HTML code :

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <select name="brand" id="brands" class="form-control"
    onchange="populate_models()">
   <option value="">برند</option>
   @foreach ($data as $catt)
    <option value="{{ $catt['id'] }}">{{ $catt['name'] }}
     ( {{$catt['count']}} )
    </option>
   @endforeach
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <select class="col-md-4" name="model[]" id="models" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="all">نام</option>
   
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

and my jquery code :

```
var populate_models;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        populate_models = function () {
            var brand_id = $('#brands').val();
            var address = '{{route('home.get_brands')}}' + '/' + brand_id;
            $.getJSON(address, function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                var models_dropdown = $("#models");
                models_dropdown.empty();

                var all_models = $("<option />");
                all_models.html("نام");
                all_models.val("all");
                models_dropdown.append(all_models);

                $(data['models']).each(function () {
                    var option = $("<option />");
                    option.html(this.cat_name);
                    option.val(this.id);
                    models_dropdown.append(option);
                });

            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please add HTML and JSON reponse in your question ?

Comment: you can check online this problem : http://yazd2020.ir/car

Comment: Span above you drop down with class **multiselect-native-select** is creating problem, make the same structure like other select box, Please add fiddle for the same so that someone can edit the code, Here it not possible to edit the code.

Comment: **Span tag with class multiselect-native-select , i don't adding to code,** because this drop down is Multiple, this class and tag added automatically into code.

Comment: Are you using any third party library to create multiselect ?

Comment: No, i just use Bootstrap Multiselect plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per document you need to call the multiselect method once you populate the select option.

Try something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#models").multiselect();
        });
        var data = {"years":[{"model":"2011"}],"models":[{"cat_name":"کورولا","id":"8"},{"cat_name":"کمری","id":"19"},{"cat_name":"لندکروز","id":"20"},{"cat_name":"هایلوکس","id":"21"},{"cat_name":"یاریس","id":"22"}]};
        function show(){
            var models_dropdown = $("#models");
                models_dropdown.empty();

                var all_models = $("<option />");
                all_models.html("نام");
                all_models.val("all");
                models_dropdown.append(all_models);

                $(data['models']).each(function () {
                    var option = $("<option />");
                    option.html(this.cat_name);
                    option.val(this.id);
                    models_dropdown.append(option);
                });
            $("#models").multiselect('rebuild');
        }
```

Here I called the `$("#models").multiselect();` This will initially create drop down,

show() is replication of you ajax call.

Here at the and you need to rebuild the multiselect.

```
$("#models").multiselect('rebuild');
```

[Reference Doc](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods)

Comment: thank you so much for your help, My problem has been resolved .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help, My problem has been resolved.
just add this code, in my code.

```html
$("#models").multiselect('rebuild');
```